# Find matrix of linear transformation in the standard basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a linear transformation $A$.

In basis ${(1,1),(1,2)}$

$A= \begin{bmatrix} -1 & -1\\4 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$

Find $A$ in the standard basis ${(1,0),(0,1)}$

The teacher told us the answer, but i have no idea how to get it:

$A= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2\\3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

The base change matrix from the basis (1,1)(1,2) to the standard basis is just the matrix
$$T=\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}$$, so you want to compute the product
$$A’=TAT^{-1}$$
which (when multiplied by a vector from the right) changes coordinates from standard basis to your basis, applies $A$ and then transforms the result back into standard basis.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If $P$ is the change of basis matrix from the standard basis to the given basis, denoting $A_s$ the matrix of the linear transformation in the standard basis, $A$ and $A_s$ satisfy the relation
$$A=P^{-1}A_s P, \quad\text{whence }A_s=PAP^{-1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

In the standard basis,

$A(1,1)=-1(1,1)+4(1,2)=(3,7)$ and

$A(1,2)=-1(1,1)+6(1,2)=(5,11)$,

so by linearity

$A(1,0)=2A(1,1)-A(1,2)=2(3,7)-(5,11)=(1,3)$ and

$A(0,1)=A(1,2)-A(1,1)=(5,11)-(3,7)=(2,4)$.